# "Объектно-ориентированная" файловая система в Windows

Tags: windows, файловая-система

Как можно организовать в Windows зависимости одних файлов от других? Чтобы один файл был классом для другого файла-класса, из которого уже можно создавать файлы-объекты. Нужно для текстовых файлов-шаблонов, являющихся частными случаями других файлов-шаблонов

Comment: А, пример, когда файл-класс - это вордовый темплейт, а файл-объект - это вордовый документ, сделанный на основе этого темплейта - Вам не подходит?

Comment: Почти в точку, но нужно, чтобы было несколько вордовых шаблонов, с одним корневым шаблоном, изменяя данные в котором менялись бы данные в других (рекурсивно). И не только для ворда. Например, для объединения текстовых списков (перенос строки как разделитель)

Comment: А можно узнать задачу, которую ты хочешь решить?

Comment: Из действующих стандартов на ум в первую очередь приходит **XML Schema**.